# Why does this work with the dot operator?

Tags: lua

I'm currently following the tutorial at http://howtomakeanrpg.com/a/classes-in-lua.html on classes and am trying to find the logic in the way the colon operator is used. From what I understand the only thing the colon operator does outside of a functions definition is to pass the table that is in front of it in as an invisible parameter.

Below I have created three monsters in different ways to try to get the logic of this. I don't understand this at all apparently because when calling the second monster it doesn't need me to pass in the table for Monster??? And why can I put in the table monster_3(which I've tested to be of the type table)  as a parameter, isn't the table: Monster the table that is passed in? Or is it simply the dot that says that Create is inside the table Monster. It just makes no sense to me at all.

I also thought that the new object is added to the parent table but when I check to see if the monster_(number) is inside the table: Monster I get nill. What??? Then where are these new monster_1,2,3 tables stored???

Thanks for having a look,

Xpali

```
   Monster = {}
function Monster:Create()
    local this =
    {
        name = "orc",
        health = 10,
        attack = 3
    }

    function this:WarCry()
        print(self.name .. ": GRAAAHH!!!")
    end

    return this

end

monster_1 = Monster:Create()
monster_2 = Monster.Create()
monster_3 = Monster.Create(monster_3)

print(monster_1.name) -- orc
print(type(monster_1)) -- table
print(type(Monster.monster_1)) -- nil

print(monster_2.name) -- orc
print(type(monster_2)) -- table
print(type(Monster.monster_2)) -- nil

print(monster_3.name) -- orc
print(type(monster_3)) -- table 
print(type(Monster.monster_3)) -- nil

monster_1:WarCry() -- orc: GRAAAHH!!!
monster_2:WarCry() -- orc: GRAAAHH!!!
    monster_3.WarCry(monster_3) -- orc: GRAAAHH!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not very expressive for class instancing, because the constructor in use has no arguments. As a result all 3 instances are identical. In addition, "Monster.monster_1" and similar are NOT instances, they are nils.

To see something more interesting I have prepared the following code sample:

```
-- Default properties values
local Monster = {
  name = "orc",
  health = 10,
  attack = 3
}

-- constructor
function Monster:Create(instance_name)
  -- take defaults from self (that is Monster table)
  instance_name = instance_name or self.name
  return {
    name = instance_name,
    health = self.health,
    attack = self.attack,
    WarCry = function(this)
      print(this.name .. ": GRAAAHH!!!")
    end
  }
end

monster_1 = Monster:Create()
monster_2 = Monster:Create("named") 
--monster_2 = Monster.Create() -- Incorrect use!
--monster_3 = Monster.Create(monster_3) -- Incorrect use!

print(monster_1.name) -- orc
print(type(monster_1)) -- table

print(monster_2.name) -- named
print(type(monster_2)) -- table

monster_1:WarCry() -- orc: GRAAAHH!!!
monster_2:WarCry() -- named: GRAAAHH!!!
```

Now the constructor has an explicit argument ("instance_name") and an implicit one (Monster table). The last is required for using "self" keyword. So we should NOT use dot syntax while instancing, this will result in an error. If we avoid "self" in the constructor definition, we can use dot syntax without errors, as you can see below:

```
-- constructor
function Monster:Create(instance_name)
  -- take defaults from self (that is Monster table)
  instance_name = instance_name or Monster.name
  return {
    name = instance_name,
    health = Monster.health,
    attack = Monster.attack,
    WarCry = function(this)
      print(this.name .. ": GRAAAHH!!!")
    end
  }
end

monster_1 = Monster:Create()
monster_2 = Monster.Create(nil, "named")
```

Pay attention to "nil" in the last call. This argument is required, because the constructor was defined by colon syntax, but we use a dot call. If we omit "nil" argument, the "named" value will be considered as a parent table in the colon context.

ADDED:

We can also create a constructor using dot syntax:

```
Monster.CreateByDot = function(instance_name)
  instance_name = instance_name or 'Noname';
  return {
    name = instance_name,
    WarCry = function(this) 
      print(this.name .. ": GRAAAHH!!!")
    end
  } 
end

monster_3 = Monster.CreateByDot()
monster_4 = Monster.CreateByDot('Fourth')

monster_3:WarCry() -- Noname: GRAAAHH!!!
monster_4:WarCry() -- Fourth: GRAAAHH!!!
```

and see argument "instance_name" in action.

Comment: Very interesting but that doesn't answer my question. Where are the instances created from Monster:Create stored? And if I say Monster:Create() isn't that the same as Monster.Create(Monster)? And if I pass in the Monster table as an argument, what actually happens to the Monster table?

Comment: Instances are stored in variables: monster_1 = Monster:Create(). monster_1 is a variable, where the instance (table type) is stored. Is it clear? If you pass an argument, you should understand whether and how it will be used inside constructor. It depends on the constructor. If our constructor does not use this argument, we can say that Monster:Create() and Monster.Create(Monster) are the same.

Comment: So Monster:Create() runs the Create function and stores it in a variable that is in front of the = sign, and Monster:Create() and Monster.Create(Monster) are the same because the function doesn't use the Monster table? You say this depends on the constructor, can you give an example of when Monster:Create() is not the same as Monster.Create(Monster)?

Comment: The reason I'm confused is because I thought that when you use the colon operator the table in front of the operator was always passed to the function behind it. But from the code in this tutorial I can't find the function of the Monster table in the function.

Comment: I have added "dot" type constructor with one argument into article. Why do you want to pass Monster itself as an argument value? What result would you like to obtain by this action? I think we can set only some properties (such as instance_name) at this stage.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to. But if you are typing Monster:Create() aren't you passing in Monster as an argument by definition? The colon means it is passed in as a hidden parameter. And when calling the function like this: monster_1 = Monster:Create() in my understanding it says this: monster_1 = Monster.Create(Monster)

Comment: ... it says this: monster_1 = Monster.Create() and use Monster as "self" inside constructor. Right, we can understand it so.

Comment: But then I am confused as to what the function is of passed in Monster as self. What happens to Monster as an argument as it passes through that function. This is the same reason why I am confused on why I don't have to pass in Monster when calling it like this monster_2 = Monster.Create().

Comment: And if I need to pass in Monster in Monster.Create() why can I pass in the object I'm creating like this?: monster_3 = Monster.Create(monster_3)

Comment: You can pass in any object or any value... But what is the goal? For example, you can adjust the constructor to take some properties of the object passed in and apply them to the new creation. We should consider both the constructor code and the creating call at the same time. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: But why can I do it in the original code. Literally what happens to the object and the table when they pass through the create function? What do they do in that function? That's what I don't understand